# Browser shortcuts saved in the desktop not working with shortcut keys

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

I have saved few browser shortcuts in the desktop and assigned shortcut keys for them. The shortcut keys worked few times and opened the URL in the browser but later stopped working. I am testing this shortcuts with both edge and chrome browser. What could be the reason the shortcut keys are not opening the URLs and showing inconsistent behavior?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this issue on my device. Does this issue only occurs to browser shortcuts? What about other shortcuts? Are you pressing them too fast?